# <ons-tab>タブをタップした時のアニメーションを変更したい(カスタマイズ）

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui, angularjs

onsen uiで以下の機能を実装したいと考えています。

タブ切り替え時のアニメーションにons-navigatorの画面遷移時に設定できる"slide"のようなアニメーションでタブを切り替えたいと考えているのですが、ons-tabbarのオプションには"slide"が設定できないので他の方法で実装したいのですが、実装方法がわかりません。

上記実装をonsen uiでどのようにすればよろしいのでしょうか？
ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授のほどよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

[replacePageで画面遷移する際のアニメーションの方向を変えたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/16634/replacepage%E3%81%A7%E7%94%BB%E9%9D%A2%E9%81%B7%E7%A7%BB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E9%9A%9B%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A2%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AE%E6%96%B9%E5%90%91%E3%82%92%E5%A4%89%E3%81%88%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)

と同様のやり方でカスタマイズすることができます。
既存の`fade(TabbarFadeAnimator)`は`Onsen UI Ver.1.3.17`の`onsenui.js` 13580行にありますので、それらや`ons-tabbar`の動作を解析し、スライド処理を実装してください。

```
var app = ons.bootstrap("myApp", ["onsen"]);
app.factory("TabbarSlideAnimator", ["TabbarAnimator", function(TabbarAnimator) {
    var TabbarSlideAnimator = TabbarAnimator.extend({
        // スライド処理
        //
        //
    });
    return TabbarSlideAnimator;
  }]);
app.run(function(TabbarView, TabbarSlideAnimator) {
    // slideを追加
    TabbarView.registerAnimator("slide", new TabbarSlideAnimator());
});
```